# No mapping... error when clicking on a unit tab on the IDE

Tags: ide

I'm working with Delphi 12. Everything was fine till today when I get the message:

```
No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
```

The message appears when I try to show the contents of any unit, clicking on the corresponding unit tab.

Follows an image showing how the error happens.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.